# Alterar programaticamente a data exibida num controle "DatePicker"?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datepicker

Estou a tentar exibir os dados de um campo de uma tabela `MySQL` num controle `DatePicker`. O código é o seguinte:

```
if (dataGridProdutos.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    DateTime selectedDate;
    DataRowView selectedRecord = (DataRowView)dataGridProdutos.SelectedItem;
    selectedDate = (DateTime)selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2];
    dataNascTextBox.Text = selectedDate.Date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
    dataNascDatePicker ????
    ...
}
```

Como posso completar esta linha que diz respeito ao `dataNascDatePicker`?

Comment: isso  dataNascDatePicker.Value=selectedDate.Date; nao funciona? veja o link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value

Comment: Já tinha tentado e não ... a não ser que me esteja a escapar algum detalhe!

Comment: O que ocorre quando voce faz isso: dataNascDatePicker.Value=selectedDate.Date; ?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim:

```
DateTime selectedDate;
DataRowView selectedRecord = (DataRowView)dataGridProdutos.SelectedItem;
...
selectedDate = (DateTime)selectedRecord.Row.ItemArray[2];
dataNascDatePicker.SelectedDate = selectedDate;
...
```